# How to supply argument to a @javaAnnotation on an avro idl file?

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation, avro

I'm trying to add a java annotation to my avro idl file (avdl file).  And I can't seem to figure out how to supply the arguments to the annotation.  Here's a simplified example

```
protocol Message {
    record Message {
        int @javaAnnotation("java.lang.SuppressWarnings") myInt = 0;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this I get

```
error: annotation @SuppressWarnings is missing a default value for the element 'value'
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings
  ^
1 error
```

But I don't really see any syntax that would allow me to pass the parameter. Here's the ticket that added this feature https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1186 for reference.

I'm using avro version `1.8.2` and using the gradle-avro plugin version `0.12.0`

I anyone could provide some insight, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write the annotation as it would appear, escaping the double quotes:

```java
protocol Message {
    record Message {
        int @javaAnnotation("java.lang.SuppressWarnings(\"unused\")") myInt = 0;
    }
}
```

The Avro compiler does nothing to strip annotation names.

Comment: this did not work for me. I tried the annotation you provided `union {null, int}  @javaAnnotation("java.lang.SuppressWarnings(\"unused\")") field = null;` and I get a parse exception `Caused by: org.apache.avro.compiler.idl.ParseException: Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "unused "" at line 22, column 80. Was expecting: ")" ...` I tried a bunch of other things - double escaping, using the triple quote string literal syntax and specifying unicode for the two quotes to no avail. I am also using avro `1.8.2` with avro gradle plugin `0.12.0`

Comment: @isaac9A huh this is interesting. Sorry I did not try this with an actual IDL definition but just in a JSON schema definition. So perhaps this is an issue with the parsing of the extra 'props' (parts beginning with @ sign) in IDL. Will try to investigate further

Comment: Yeah it looks like the parser does something funky with the annotation. I am going to try and take a look at the parsing classes to see what they do. It doesn't help that the documentation for avro idl records is very sparse and difficult to come by. Please do let me know if you find anything out thanks!

Comment: @isaac9A I just tried this with both Ryan's example and using a Union as in your snippet which worked on 1.8.2. I did not use the gradle plugin but just the avro-tools idl command.

Comment: @IvanG. We're able to get the to work as well, but the issue we're trying to solve is the get the annotations onto the generated Java classes.

Comment: @IvanG Thanks again, got it to work as you suggested - unbeknown to me, there was a preprocessing routine in the build.gradle file which stripped backslashes, causing me to get an error. Once I fixed that I was able to successfully compile the idl record and see the correct annotations in the generated java classes!